# Maximum Value From List with Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to get the dictionary with the biggest value in the key 
'points'.

So, I have the following list and I'm trying to create a function where the output will be the item from the list (in this case a dictionary) with the biggest value in the key **points**).

```
[ {"name":"John","points":4} , {"name": "Michael", "points":10} ]
```

I want the output to be:

```
{"name": "Michael", "points":10}
```

I 'm not posting any code because I have no idea of how to do this.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
max(scores, key=lambda item: item['points'])
```

---

```
>>> scores = [ {"name":"John","points":4} , {"name": "Michael", "points":10} ]
>>> max(scores, key=lambda item: item['points'])
{'points': 10, 'name': 'Michael'}
>>>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the help! :)